# Python Power set , can't figure out my error

Tags: python, powerset

My code will crash and run forever:

```
def subsets(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """
    results = [[]]
    for num in nums:
        for result in results:
            results.extend([result + [num]])
    return results
```

While I googled, and find similar solution:

```
def subsets(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """
    results = [[]]
    for num in nums:
        results.extend([result + [num] for result in results])
    return results
```

What's the difference here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The critical part is this:

```
for result in results:
    results.extend([result + [num]])
```

Here, you are iterating over the `results` list. An iterator is always something living, that does not finish until you actually reached the end. For lists, you can simply imagine this as a pointer that starts at the first element, and then keeps going to the next until it reaches the end.

Except that in your case, you are adding an element (since `[result + [num]]` is a one-element list) to the `results` list on every iteration. So as the iterator keeps going forward, you keep adding one element to the end making sure the iterator can never reach the end.

As a general rule, you should never modify the collection you are currently iterating. So in this case, you shouldn’t modify `results` while you are iterating the same thing.

And that’s exactly what the following line in that other solution avoids:

```
results.extend([result + [num] for result in results])
```

This uses a list comprehension and is essentially equivalent to this:

```
tmp = []
for result in results:
    tmp.append(result + [num])
results.extend(tmp)
```

As you can see, `results` is not modified *while* iterating over it. The `tmp` list is first created, and then once that’s done, the `results` list is modified by extending it by the whole `tmp` list.